# how to make datalist display options in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a text input with a datalist.

```html
      <input type="text" list="languageList"/>
     <datalist id="languageList">
    <option value="abc" />
    <option value="bac" />
    <option value="cbd" />
    </datalist>
```

if user type 'a' only values that start with a (in this case 'abc') is displayed. I want to display all values that  has occurrence of 'a' anywhere in the value (in this case both abc and bac should be displayed).

Is it possible? If so, how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code seems right :) I have checked in chrome and FF

Comment: When I type "a", "abc" **and** "bac" are being displayed to me. I'm in Chrome 54.0.2840.99. What browser do you have?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this markup in? It works perfectly in Firefox 49.0.1.

Comment: yes, it is working fine in chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit) . This snippet only display only 'abc'. So its must be the compatibility issue then

Comment: @sam check [support of datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) & also [supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are having some issues with datalist browser compatibility. See the chart below:

[Datalist Browser Compatibility Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcw6q.png)

Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

Hope my answer give you some help.

Comment: @sam if the users browsers are out of date you should talk to the IT Manager to solve this issue or create a snippet to alert the user of this issue and what it can affect his experience with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of datalist is matching will takes at any position. In your case, if you type 'a' both 'abc' and 'bac' will display. Please check the functionality again. If you had any doubt please visit below link 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: how to deal if users browser is below given standards